# How do I log into a postgresql server hosted on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have my RDS postgreSQL running and have the correct inbound connections in my security group. I also have an EC2 instance running with Ubuntu 14.04. What I want to know is how can I connect to my RDS through terminal? Am I even able to do this?

Comment: [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) this is what you need

Comment: If you mean ssh then no, you can't do that. RDS is a managed service and you don't get access to the underlying operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean ssh to the RDS operating system, then no, you cannot do that. If you mean access postgres using command line to run SQL commands, then yes, it is possible.

According to AWS manuals you can connect using psql command, there are complete instructions in this link:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html

I quote the part I believe answers your question:

> **Using psql to Connect to a PostgreSQL DB Instance**
>
> If your client computer has PostgreSQL installed, you can use a local
>   instance of psql to connect to a PostgreSQL DB instance. To connect to
>   your PostgreSQL DB instance using psql, you need to provide host
>   information and access credentials.
>
> The following format is used to connect to a PostgreSQL DB instance on
>   Amazon RDS:
>
> **For Linux, OS X, or Unix:**
>
> psql \    --host= \    --port= \
>   --username  \    --password  \    --dbname=
>
> **For Windows:**
>
> psql ^    --host= ^    --port= ^
>   --username  ^    --password  ^    --dbname=
>
> For example, the following command connects to a database called
>   mypgdb on a PostgreSQL DB instance called mypostgresql using
>   fictitious credentials:
>
> psql --host=mypostgresql.c6c8mwvfdgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
>   --port=5432 --username=awsuser --password --dbname=mypgdb

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can not SSH into and RDS Amazon instance. You can access the database through psql or pgadmin remotely though. There are a number of ways to set that up depending on your security requirements. Basically you need to make port 5432 available to the box you want to access the database from.

Probably the most secure way is to SSH into an EC2 instance and access the database from the EC2 instance. You can setup SSH tunneling to do this automatically.

You could setup expensive VPN stuff with Amazon, but that's expensive.

You could just open the port directly to the RDS box. A little dangerous though. Make sure you are using SSL and best to not open it up to the whole world but just the IP for your office. You have to make sure that this is setup up properly in both the postgres config and the VPC config.